# Saving data to server via AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, knockout.js

having some issues with my save function on knockout. I was following the tutorial on the Knockout site http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/bGsRH/. WHen I implement the code to my site I get an error  an error 400 Bad request stating that my JSON data is invalid. After debugging a bit more I see that it`s returning [object, object] instead of my modified JSON data.

To give a little context, I basically have a table with my list of data and each row has their edit button. Upon clicking the edit button it opens a modal and shows the data of the selected item. The issue occurs when I try to modify and then save the data.

Here is my javascript code I have so far, would anyone know what im missing?:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function EmployeeModal() {
     var self = this;
     self.Employees = ko.observableArray([]);

    //Start of select/edit functions
    //This codes allows to pass selected data to the hidden modal
     self.currentEmployee = ko.observable(null);
     self.showEmployee = function(vm){
         self.currentEmployee(vm);
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
     };
     //END of select/edit functions
     //Start of the save function
     self.save = function() {
        var New_Incident_URL = '../../../../_vti_bin/listData.svc/GDI_PROD_Incidents';
        var UPDATE_Incident_URL = '../../../../_vti_bin/listData.svc/GDI_PROD_Incidents('+ encodeURIComponent($('#Incident_ID').val())+')';
        var createIncidentUrl = $('#Incident_ID').val() != '' ? UPDATE_Incident_URL : New_Incident_URL;

        var CREATE_Headers = {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"};
        var UPDATE_Headers = {"accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose","X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE","If-Match":"*"};
        var headertype = $('#Incident_ID').val() != '' ? UPDATE_Headers : CREATE_Headers;   

        $.ajax(createIncidentUrl, {
            data: {
                json: ko.toJSON({

                        Description: this.Description,

                        Incident: this.Incident

                })
            },
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: headertype,
            success: function(result) {
                alert(ko.toJSON(result));
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            }
        });
     };


     //Start - Go get data from Sharepoint.
    $.getJSON("../../../../_vti_bin/listData.svc/GDI_PROD_Incidents?$filter=ÉtatValue%20ne%20%27Fermé%27&$orderby=PrioritéValue desc",
        function (data) {
        if (data.d.results) {
            self.Employees(ko.toJS(data.d.results));
            }
        }
    );  
    //END - Go get data from Sharepoint.

}
     $(document).ready(function () {
         ko.applyBindings(new EmployeeModal());
     });

</script>
```

EDIT:
Here is an example of my data from the server.

```
   [{
        ID: "123",
        Description: "The server x is unavailable",
        Incident: "1234"
    }, {
        ID: "124",
        Description: "The router located downtown is down",
        Incident: "12345"
    }, {
        ID: "125",
        Description: "Fiber optic cable downtown is flapping",
        Incident: "123456"
    }, {
        ID: "126",
        Description: "Network unvailable at the beaver site",
        Incident: "1234567",
    }];
```

Comment: Can you explain in one sentence the relations between the objects in your data model? From what I see there is an "incident list" that contains multiple "incident" objects, each of whom contains an "employee" object. Is that about right? (I intend to set your viewmodel layout straight, because it is pretty convoluted right now.)

Comment: Hi Tomalak, I have an "incident list" that contains multiple "incident" objects. I edited the main post to add an example of what my server data would look like if that helps. I based myself off an example code that contained Employees but my data really just contains Incidents. Ill need to clean that up but just trying to get this working before I start messing with it.

Comment: Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rqwku4kb/ - I would have created a proper answer pointing out the considerations for all the changes, but I'm out of time for today.

Comment: Tomalak, thank you so much for that, i've been going trough the code and it's solid. THanks again!

Comment: Question tough, you used a .get method to get my data but not returning in jason by default. Is there a way to includes headers in a .get to return me what i need?

Comment: You can keep using  `.getJSON()` if that helps, but setting the Content-Type header properly is usually  everything that's necessary for jQuery to do the right thing. Also, if your target server does not accept native MERGE requests, this can be configured as well.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use getjson but was a bit confused on how to pass the params in the url of the getjson. I tried this `$.getJSON(Incident.BASE_URL+params, function(data) {  ...` but dosent seem to like that or this either `$.getJSON((Incident.BASE_URL+params), function(data) {  ...`  would you know how to properly pass it?

Comment: `$.getJSON()` works exactly the like `$.get()` in this regard. URL parameters are passed as an object, in second argument. Not sure what you are trying there.